# What are recent, high-quality surveys on NLP topics?

Tags: reference-request, natural-language-processing

In particular POS tagging, dependency and constituent parsing. This is not really my field of study but I would really like to be able to make informed claims on what precisions current top systems achieve (and what top systems for each task are).

This paper of a (high quality) system (http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0398) we have used in experiements uses benchmarks from 2000, 2003 and 2005. But I don't know if more recent systems have outperformed those or new benchmark tasks exists.

Comment: Have you google-scholar-ed?